# MICE, ordinal data

Tags: stata, missing-data, likert

I am new to imputation and EFA. I need to do EFA using 25 items on a Likert scale 1-5 or 1-4.  25% of sample have at least 1 variable with missing value. All items have some missing values. I need to use MICE to impute the missing values, but using Stata running  into 'perfect predictions' issue. Getting error message even with `augment` option. my code below

```
mi set mlong
mi register imputed A...Y
mi impute chained (ologit, augment) A..Y, add (5) rseed (345)
```

error message

```
convergence not achieved
ologit failed to converge on observed data
error occurred during imputation of A...Y
```

Appreciate any help with solving this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to a problem with your dataset rather than a programming issue.

Comment: The data has missing values, but because it is all ordinal it is tricky to impute. I can do the imputation in SAS,I also want to see if I can also do it with STATA. It is definitely a coding/syntax question.

Comment: That comment doesn't make the question any easier to answer because if the data allow imputation in SAS but not in Stata,  what it is about the data and/or the different syntax that makes that so?  A vote to close expresses a view that the question can't be answered on the information given. I would be happy to be wrong on that.

Comment: I wrote 25 separate equations for each item with fewer likely predictors with a single Proc MI statement. I reviewed STATA mi documentation, but it does not have examples addressing my situation. Meaning, how do I write 25 statements for each item using some of the other items as predictors in STATA? I am wondering if I have to create 25 subsets of data in stata for predicting each item then concatenate the data.  This must be a common problem for those who do scale development given items are often in Likert scale and respondents often don't answer questions, which will cause missing values.

Comment: That’s helpful detail now  but I think you’d be better off taking that to Statalist or StataCorp technical support. People watching Stata here have a fair total of experience but no one with extensive  -mi- experience has picked this up

Comment: Thank you Nick. I will do a search to see how i could get help from them.